# How to structure database for unread item alerts per user

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, cookies

I just have a general database theory question. I have a need to make something similar to showing what posts/items a user has viewed or not (such as in a forum) or an unread email message. What I have is there are posts that multiple users can view, but it needs to separate by user who has actually viewed it. So if User A viewed Post 1, it would no longer show that Post 1 is a new item to view, but to User B, it would still show that Post 1 is a new item to view.

I've search for other ideas and one of them is to get a timestamp of when the user last logged in, but I actually need to keep track of the posts they've seen as opposed to posts that have happened since they last logged in.

I would like a MySQL database solution if possible, but I'm open to cookies if that is a must. I could do this on my own and just figure it out, but I'd appreciate any advice on how to properly structure a table(s) to make this the most efficient. Also, bandwidth and storage is not issue.

Comment: You could take a look at how vBulletin and other forum systems handle it, to get an idea. Or maybe [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/), since I guess vBulletin you have to buy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While reviewing the [relevant schema for phpBB](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop/phpBB/install/schemas/mysql_41_schema.sql#L819), I found the following:

```
# Table: 'phpbb_topics_track'
CREATE TABLE phpbb_topics_track (
    user_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    topic_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    forum_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    mark_time int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, topic_id),
    KEY topic_id (topic_id),
    KEY forum_id (forum_id)
) CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_bin`;
```

And:

```
# Table: 'phpbb_forums_track'
CREATE TABLE phpbb_forums_track (
    user_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    forum_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    mark_time int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, forum_id)
) CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_bin`;
```

Then I [look here in their wiki](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_topics_track):

> This table keeps record for visited topics in order to mark them as
>   read or unread. We use the mark_time timestamp in conjunction with
>   last post of topic x's timestamp to know if topic x is read or not.
>
> In order to accurately tell whether a topic is read, one has to also
>   check phpbb_forums_track.

So essentially they have a lookup table to store the data associated with a user's viewing of a topic (thread), and then check it against the timestamp in the forum view table, to determine whether the topic has been viewed by the user.

Comment: This is just what I needed. I'll just create the phpbb_forums_track table and that should get the job done that I need. Thank ya

Comment: No problem. I was going to post the location of the query which accesses the data too. I'll let you know if I find it.

Comment: Also consider you're probably going to want to cache the data in the user's session on the server, so you're constantly calling that query (which is probably slow). Then build in functionality to push the view data to the cache at the same time it's recorded in the db.

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly - Here's the part that does the views setup for the user: https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop/phpBB/includes/functions_display.php#L85

Answer (score 2):

Just create a simple cross-reference table (`read_posts` or something):

```
user_id|post_id
----------------
2      | 132
53     | 43
....
```

Make sure that both of these columns are indexed (especially important that the `user_id` be indexed) and then use a join (or a sub-query) to select unread posts for the logged in user. If you're just trying to show a list of unread posts, for example, you just run:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `post_id` FROM `read_posts` WHERE `user_id`='[$USER ID]')
ORDER BY [your ordering clause]
```

Comment: Wouldn't the performance of a subselect and `IN` clause prove problematic for something like checking page views? Unless of course there was a forward-looking caching of that data in the user session.

Comment: Subqueries are potentially a lot less efficient than joins, but I think in this case there would be no performance hit for the subquery... complex subqueries will sometimes not "choose" the most efficient execution order, but I think in this case there is no ambiguity and performance should be fine with even large numbers of rows - especially with the proper use of indexing. If you have some benchmarks that suggest a join would be faster in this case I'd be very interested.

Comment: You're right I believe. I still would probably use a `JOIN`, but that might be more preference. Anyhow, I think the best approach is a combination of session caching and dual cache/session updates when the user views a post/topic. That way the query is really only running during a login process or session setup, which would be efficient and manageable.

Comment: At least with the phpBB developers, it looks like they use a `JOIN`: https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/develop/phpBB/includes/functions_display.php#L85

Comment: Yeah, that's not surprising (I think that if you ask mysql to `EXPLAIN` they will actually be functionally identical in this instance). In general it seems to me that people will often exclusively use `JOIN`s, probably based on the notion that they're always faster. It's true that `JOIN`s will more often than not be as good or better, but there are lots of examples where subqueries are more efficient... and in cases of equivalency it's just a matter of taste (I find `subqueries` more readable, but that's just me)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I use and also often prefer subqueries for the same reason, and I'm certainly no querymeister extraordinaire. My perception of `IN` and subqueries is that they need to be well-understood to use efficiently in certain situations and applications. So I see what you're getting at as far as the structure of the query not indicating concerns that may lead to poor execution times.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this description I would use a simple table with maybe 3 columns.

1. User ID
2. Post ID
3. Timestamp First Viewed

When a user views a post, add a row to the table. If a row does not exist in the table for a given user/post id combo, then they have not viewed the post.